# Continuity of additive set function

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

Additive function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have the property that if it is continuous on a single point, it is continuous on the entire domain.

I wonder if set functions $f: \mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined on a measurable space $(S, \mathcal{F})$ have the same property when it is finite and additive.

Note: Continuity of a set function is defined as both continous from above and from below.